# Imaginary Number in Logic

Tags: logic, soft-question

The equation $x^2 = -1$ was once said to have no solution. Then the number $i$ was discovered (or invented?) and our number system got richer. In particular, in this new wonderful world of complex numbers, we can prove the fundamental theorem of algebra, a consequence of which is that every polynomial is solvable in the complex domain.

In a similar vein, the logical statement $P = \lnot P$ has no solution in the set $\{True, False\}$. This is the well known liar's paradox, and has appeared in various forms throughout logic e.g. Russel's paradox, Godel's incompleteness theorem.

Now say we invent a *new* logical value $iTrue$, an imaginary one if you like, that is defined as the solution of the equation $P = \lnot P$. Our propositions would then range over $\{True, False, iTrue\}$.

**My Question:** Could this new system, or one like it, free us from such paradoxical, unsolvable logical statements in an analogous way to the way complex numbers freed us from unsolvable polynomials?

**My Thoughts:** I am skeptical of the above system. I feel that it may help us "solve" some paradoxes but not all. Furthermore it is not obvious what these solutions would *mean*. On the other hand, it would be lovely if the analogy with complex numbers actually worked on a more rigorous footing.

Comment: Somewhat vaguely connected to your suggestion is *paraconsistent logic* (please see Wikipedia).

Comment: Another possible solution is [Three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) (e.g. by Kleene) with the truth values $\{ false, unknown$, and $true \}$. See also [Many-Valued Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-manyvalued/).

Comment: $x^2=-1$ does not have a solution. If you give $\mathbb R^2$ a field structure, $x^2 = (-1,0)$ has a solution.

Comment: @JohnDouma, $-1$ is often written as shorthand for $-1 + 0i$.

Comment: @ColmBhandal Yes, but my point is that saying $x^2 = -1$ has a solution is completely false. The complex numbers don't give us the ability to construct a square whose area is $-1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas nice link. It also led me to Dialetheism which is pretty much what my question scrapes at.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Cool links. I guess that basically answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnDouma $i^2 = -1$. So $x = i$ is a solution to $x^2 = -1$. I don't follow your argument about constructing squares.

Comment: @ColmBhandal What is $i$? It is shorthand for the complex number $(0,1)$. If you square it you don't get the real number $-1$, you get the complex number $(-1,0)$. When we say that $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$ we really mean that $\mathbb R$ is isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @JohnDouma, I don't like that representation, it's too strict. Just use $-1 = -1 + 0i$ and you *do* get that subset inclusion. Or do you also challenge that equation? Maths would sure be ugly if we put everything into parenthetical straight jackets all the time!

Comment: @ColmBhandal Yes, and if you just let $P = \lnot P$ you'll be able to prove every theorem you can think of.

Comment: In the first paragraph, you meant *algebra*, not *arithmetic*.

Comment: Assuming you mean equivalence, $P \Leftrightarrow \neg P$ is not the liar's paradox. $P \leftrightarrow \neg P$ is always false. The liar's paradox is neither false nor true.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva well spotted, thanks. I had the other term floating around my head.

Comment: @Chester I chose equality rather than equivalence to avoid that particular confusion. Consider this version of the liar's sentence "This sentence is false." Let $P$ be the value/meaning of the sentence (assuming it exists). Interpreting the sentence as a definition, we get $P := (P \equiv false)$ or $P := \lnot P$ and so the equation $P = \lnot P$ characterises the paradox (sort of).

Comment: @JohnDouma, that depends. I have learned something fascinating today about paraconsistent logics and many valued logics in which the principle of explosion you allude to *doesn't* hold. And this is the crux of the whole question!

Comment: @ColmBhandal what I'm saying is that the analogy doesn't hold. The statement, $x^2 = -1$, is false $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. This is the opposite of a tautology, i.e. a contradiction when restricted to $\mathbb{R}$. There is no paradox.

Comment: @Chester, the analogy is between true/false as *values* and numbers as *values*. Admittedly, true and false are slippery concepts once you start using them this way. In $\mathbb{R}$, there is no value that satisfies that quadratic. In the set $\{true, false\}$, there is no value that satisfies $P = \lnot P$. In the former case, we extend our system to accommodate solutions to the equation. In a similary way, extending logic accommodates solutions to $P = \lnot P$.

Comment: Right, so this is a question about how changing the underlying algebraic structure changes the solution set to an algebraic equation.

Comment: Yep that's it basically :)

Comment: The symbolism "$P = \neg P$" is a bit confusing, since it seems to imply that the sentences are equal, which is obviously not true (one has a negation sign, while the other doesn't -- assuming unique readability). Notice that the propositional calculus generally doesn't have a symbol for equality, so the formula can't be part of the language either. What you seem to want to say is something more like "$V(\phi) = V(\neg \phi)$", where $\phi$ is a variable for formulas and $V$ is a given truth assignment. As pointed out, this happens in three-valued logic. But it won't deal with Yablo's paradox.

Comment: Sorry, I meant *Curry's* paradox in the above.

Comment: What larger problems would it solve? We  know of several satisfactory resolutions of the various paradoxes that don't involve strange new forms of logic. And good old fashioned true-or-false logic  has been remarkably successful in mathematics, science and engineering to date. Anything else would be a very hard sell indeed.

Comment: what you intend to make is called fuzzy logic [high,average,low].

Comment: @DanChristensen I share your skepticism of the above for practical uses; I just thought it would be a nice thing to explore.

Comment: @Agawa001 yes I suppose fuzzy logic would do it if you take high, average, low as $0, 0.5, 1$ and negation as $1 - P$. Then you get $1 - 0.5 = 0.5$. Nice.

Comment: @Nagase yes, it's the semantics of the formula, rather than the syntax that we want. On reading the link in Dan Arthan's answer, I suppose another way of writing what you have is $|P| = |\lnot P|$, where $|P|$ is the value of sentence $P$. But generally I like to take by *convention* that we're talking about semantics, and when syntax is intended, to use quotation marks or something e.g. "$P$" is not equal "$\lnot P$". I believe semantics-by-default is the convention that most people follow in maths, programming, natural language, otherwise things would be very cumbersome to write.

Comment: @ColmBhandal I'm not suggesting that all mathematical inquiries have an immediate practical application to be worthwhile. It's just that if your primary motivation is to resolve or work around various known paradoxes, there are easier, more intuitve ways to do it.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I suppose I didn't really have a practical aim, I just got overwhelmed with the beauty of complex numbers and infatuated with the idea that there might be something analogous in logic!

Comment: It may seem like nitpicking, but it really isn't., because in general there's no way to express what you want to express in a purely propositional language. Notice that if we're talking about valuations in general, then there's no problem (even in a classical setting) with defining a valuation (a function from sentences to truth values) such that $V(\phi) = V(\neg \phi)$. Of course, such a valuation wouldn't be Boolean, and would probably be useless (though you never know), but it wouldn't be "paradoxical". (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) In order to obtain a real paradox or contradiction (such as the liar, to which you allude -- incidental, notice that the Gödelian sentence is *not* an instance of the liar, since it's not paradoxical at all!), one needs a way of coding semantic notions inside the language of the theory (e.g. gödel numbering). This is far from a trivial matter, which is why Tarski's and Gödel's theorems are so ingenious.

Comment: @Nagase I completely agree that the ingenuity of Godel's proof was in the encoding, and I'm aware that the Godel sentence is not an *instance* of the liar paradox, but the *idea* comes from the liar paradox. That is, I'm sure when Godel himself was constructing his sentence, he had in mind the idea of "This sentence cannot be proven" which is very similar to "This sentence is false". Anyway, these are very subtle issues, which could be discussed at length in their own right, but they detract from the main theme of the question. The answer below by Rob Arthan is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: $iTrue$ is probably owned by Apple, so try something else.

Comment: @AlexM. hahahahaha

Comment: In www.fq.math.ca/Problems/Advanced_Problems_NOV2009.pdf Luca proved that $n$ is and odd perfect number if and only if $n\sigma(2n)=\sigma(n)(n+\sigma(n))$. I don't know how relate this with your question, but I don't know what is the previous equation involving $\sigma(n)$ or condition to be an OPN (truly this arithmetic function has a form, that seems polynomial over the primes but that isn't). Secondly we can made computations when se assume for a prime power that $gcd(p^a,n)=1$. This is as a slice of something. It isn't neccesary a response for this comment.

Comment: @JohnDouma The statement "$x^2 = −1$ has a solution" is not false, it's meaningless unless you specify *where* you're looking for a solution (and usually this is clear from context). "$x^2 = -1$ has a solution in $\mathbb{R}$" is false. "$x^2 = -1$ has a solution in $\mathbb{C}$" is true. There is a complex number called $-1$; you're not obligated to write pairs like $(-1,0)$ when you talk about complex numbers, and in fact you shouldn't if you want anyone to understand you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a vast literature on many-valued logics. Lukasiewicz's original 3-valued logic is perhaps the simplest such logic and the extra truth value $P$ satisfies your formula $P \iff \lnot P$. Lukasiewicz developed this into what are now called [Lukasiewicz logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81ukasiewicz_logic) that have been intensively studied and generalised over the years. One of these generalisations is the subject of [fuzzy logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic), which has practical applications, e.g. to model situations where knowledge is imperfect.

See  http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lukasiewicz/ for more information about Lukasiewicz's work and http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-manyvalued/ for a survey of many-valued logics.

Comment: "Possibly"- that's exactly the kind of solution I was looking for! Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You may be underestimating what was involved in the creation of the complex number system. It's not just a matter of introducing a symbol $i$ and declaring that $i^2=-1$. Rather, it's important that much of what people knew about real numbers also applies to complex numbers; specifically, $\mathbb C$ is a field of characteristic zero (though not an ordered field). So people could continue to manipulate equations (though not inequalities) involving complex numbers just as they did with real numbers.  It turned out that the properties of real numbers that persist when one passes to complex numbers are enough to give an interesting and useful theory (and later, people found additional properties of $\mathbb C$, like algebraic closure, that make it  even more interesting and useful).

Analogously, it would do little good to introduce a new truth value and declare it to be equal to its negation. One would need to show that the new system of truth values retains enough of the properties of the traditional system so that people can continue to reason more or less as they are accustomed to do.

Comment: **Q:** Is it good to introduce a truth value equal to its negation? **A:** Maybe...?

Comment: @AsafKaragila your comment has two levels, which is nice. Yes if we defined 1 as true and 0 as false, with maybe as 0.5, and negation as $1 - x$, then we can make something that works.

Comment: Andreas yeah to claim that the complex number system was simply a gimmick to solve that one tiny equation is probably a bit of an overstatement. It's probably more correct to say it was the only way to develop a fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 3):

As Rob Arthan says, there's a vast literature on this topic, only some of it in application to the paradoxes.

As a solution to paradoxes like the liar, though, the introduction of a third truth-value meets an immediate difficulty, the so-called "strengthened liar":

`This sentence is not true.`

Comment: Very good. So if we represented truth/falsehood on a fuzzy scale e.g. the interval $[0, 1]$, with true as $1$, then any value in the interval $[0, 1)$ would imply the value is $1$, which would in turn imply the value is in $[0, 1)$, and so we're back to paradox land. Hence my skepticism in the question.

Comment: In practice, mathematicians don't define function symbols everywhere, and probably mostly not predicate symbols either. E.g., the slope of vertical lines is "undefined"; using classical logic, one must choose between saying (dishonestly) that lines are perpendicular if and only if their slopes are negative reciprocals or (somewhat pedantically) that oblique lines are perpendicular if and only if their slopes are negative reciprocals. Using my favorite 3-valued logic one can honestly and non-pedantically say that "lines be perpendicular if true and only if their slopes be negative reciprocals".

Answer (score 1):

Your introduction to the question seems to be very similar than the thoughts of L. H. Kauffman in [Virtual Logic](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/VirtualLogic.pdf) and [Imaginary Values](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/ImaginaryValues.pdf). Either you were inspired by them or it could be worth checking them.

Regarding your question, it seems that you are looking for a logic where the Law of Excluded Middle is not an axiom. So, I would suggest to check the field of [paraconsitent logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic).